# Как создан API платежных систем?

Tags: api, платежные-терминалы

Здравствуйте, я хотел бы на маленьком примере узнать как создан API платежных систем, а что нужно для стороннего сайта от платежной системы и как сторонний сайт взаимодействует с данной платежной системой (отправляет в платежную систему информацию - переводит средства)?

Comment: техническая документация yandex kassa поможет "отцу русской демократии".

Comment: Большинство платежных систем очень похожи в интерфейсах. Посмотрите API любой системы и получите представление